# How to check parent folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, parent, filepath

I have get my website path using `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` (like this `C:/personal/Website/page.aspx`)

Web service is always located on page.aspx parent of parent folder (like this `C:/personal/Service/service.asmx` ). I get the webservice-path using a ABC.dll in `servicePath` variable like this string `servicePath="C:/personal/Service/service.asmx"`.

How to check service path against website path?

```
If (GetWebPath()== GetServicePath())
{
     // ... do something
}     

private string GetWebPath()
    {
        string path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
        string[] array = path.Split('\\');
        string removeString = "";
        for(int i = array.Length; --i >= 0; )
        {
            removeString = array[array.Length - 2];
            break;
        }
        path = path.Replace(@"\" + removeString + @"\", "");
        return path;
    }

    private string GetServicePath()
    {
        string path = @"C:\MNJ\OLK\ABC.asmx"
        string[] array = path.Split('\\');
        string removeString = "";
        for(int i = array.Length; --i >= 0; )
        {
            removeString = @"\" + array[array.Length - 2] + @"\" + array[array.Length - 1];
            path = path.Replace(removeString, "");
            break;
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Comment: Eno what u dont understand please tell me i will elaborate it...

Comment: Eno see below comment....

Comment: Service path D:\data\webspace\MPS.3.0\SPM\Server.asmx

Comment: Web Path D:\data\webspace\Personal\Jo\Handeler\CS_Web\website\

Comment: actually what i want "CS_Web" is parent folder. "SPM" folder is also located in "CS_Web" .I have to check "SPM" folder parent and "website" folder parent is same or not.

Comment: In live application is any path ..Dont like above but the base is "Service and "website" is in same folder..I have to check service runnning from the website parent folder or not

Comment: Do you really understand what these methods do??

Comment: yes get servicepath and getwebsitePath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string webPath = @"C:\blabla\CS_Web\website\";
string servicePath = @"C:\blabla\CS_Web\SPM\Server.asmx";

if(Path.GetDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(servicePath))==Path.GetDirectoryName(webPath)
{
   //You do something here
}
```

You have to up page to parent folder using Path.GetDirectoryName()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.Web.Server.MapPath(webPath);
```

This will return the physical file path of the currently executing web file.

More information can be found here: [System.Web.Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Providing you want to check the following pathes:

```
string webPath = @"C:\blabla\CS_Web\website\";
string servicePath = @"C:\blabla\CS_Web\SPM\Server.asmx";
```

you should call

```
string webPathParentDir = GetParentDirectoryName(webPath);
string servicePathParentDir = GetParentDirectoryName(servicePath);

if (servicePathParentDir.Equals(webPathParentDir, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // ... do something
}
```

with method:

```
private string GetParentDirectoryName(string path)
{
    string pathDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(servicePath);

    return new DirectoryInfo(pathDirectory).Parent.FullName;
}
```

Comment: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: Could you specify the path with these illegal characters?

Comment: Service path D:\data\webspace\MPS.3.0\SPM\Server.asmx

Comment: Web Path D:\data\webspace\Personal\Jo\Handeler\CS_Web\website\

Comment: actually what i want "CS_Web" is parent folder "SPM" folder is also located in  "CS_Web" ..I have to check "SPM" folder parent and "website" folder parent...

Comment: In live application is any path ..Dont like above but the base is "Service and "website" is in same folder..I have to check service runnning from the website parent folder or not

Comment: It's strange, I've just tried both web and service path, and it didn't throw any error. You must have different webPath and servicePath variables values..

Comment: See my comment u will konw what exactly i want

Comment: Have I finally understood what you meant?:)